# PHP and SQL one page insert into database

Tags: php, sql

I have written a PHP page with a form on the submit button I set the action to the PHP form page.

```
 <form id="form1" method="post" action="../control_lbs/lbs_trace.php">
```

The INSERT INTO is basic sql load information to the database.

The problem i have every time I open the page it sends blank information to the rows. Is there away I can prevent this from happening?

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO lbs_trace_etrack (lbs_msisdn, lbs_req_by, lbs_date_req,     
 lbs_reason, lbs_station, lbs_cas, lbs_traced_by) 
       VALUES     
    ('$_POST[lbs_msisdn]','$_POST[lbs_req_by]','$_POST[lbs_date_req]','$_POST[lbs_reason]'
 ,'$_POST[lbs_station]','$_POST[lbs_cas]','$_POST[lbs_traced_by]')";
```

The above is my PHP action code

This is the new code and full code I use

```
 if ($con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)) {
    if ( !empty($_POST["send"])) {

       $sql = "INSERT INTO lbs_trace_etrack (lbs_msisdn, lbs_req_by, lbs_date_req,    lbs_reason, lbs_station, lbs_cas, lbs_traced_by) 
       VALUES    ('$_POST[lbs_msisdn]','$_POST[lbs_req_by]','$_POST[lbs_date_req]','$_POST[lbs_reason]','$_POST[lbs_station]','$_POST[lbs_cas]','$_POST[lbs_traced_by]')";
        if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql;
            echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
            echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
        }
```

On refresh or page entry it still gives me blank info on Database

Comment: Add a check on your page to see if the form has been submitted before running your SQL.

Comment: modify code like this.. if(isset($_POST['submit_button_name']){ /*insert query here*/ }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13045279/1288198

Comment: Put your code inside such condition.where Submit1 is the name of button for form submitting.if ( isset( $_POST['Submit1'] ) ) { }

Comment: $con is not needed in the mysql_query. It would be needed if you use mysqli in procedural style (and switching to mysqli is a good thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `isset()` to see if the $_POST variables are set. I've use `$_POST` in the example below, I suggest you give the submitbutton a name (like `example`) and use `isset($_POST['example'])`:

```
if( isset($_POST) ){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO lbs_trace_etrack (lbs_msisdn, lbs_req_by, lbs_date_req, lbs_reason, lbs_station, lbs_cas, lbs_traced_by)
            VALUES(
                '".$_POST['lbs_msisdn']."',
                '".$_POST['lbs_req_by']."',
                '".$_POST['lbs_date_req']."',
                '".$_POST['lbs_reason']."',
                '".$_POST['lbs_station']."',
                '".$_POST['lbs_cas']."',
                '".$_POST['lbs_traced_by']."'
            )";
  echo $sql; // echo it to see if it has any values
  // print_r($_POST); // in case the query is still empty, uncomment this. It will show you the values in the POST array
}
```

Comment: I have changed as shown in my edit but it still sends blank to the database

Comment: It might have something to do with quotes, I've updated my answer to a more readable format. I've also added the echo, this way you can see what the actual query turns out to be. If it has empty values, the post array does not have any values.

Comment: I suggest you find out what makes the difference instead of copy/pasting my code, for future reference

Comment: I think I have puzzled that out if I am correct the way I was posting the values from the form the '".$_POST['lbs_traced_by']."' what you have shows the specific to look for and without the point there it did not look for the completed form in that text field?

Comment: I don't understand what you just posted. I suggest you look around for information about 'variables in strings'