# PHP contact form is sent always

Tags: php, forms

I have this form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <div>
    <span><label>Name</label></span>
    <span><input name="userName" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span><label>Email</label></span>
    <span><input name="userEmail" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span><label>Phone</label></span>
    <span><input name="userPhone" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span><label>Subject</label></span>
    <span><textarea name="userMsg"> </textarea></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span><input type="submit" value="Send!"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

And the following PHP code on the same page because the `action` is `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)) {
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userName']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userEmail']);
    $phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userPhone']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userMsg'] . $phone);

    $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

    $to = 'myEmail';
    $subject = 'subject';
    $headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

But when a user hasn't submitted the form and just visits the contact form page, I get a blank email.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you find out you get a blank email? What did you do to reproduce that problem? Hitting F5 after a real POST or just visiting this page without having been there before.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['userName']))` $_POST is always set

Comment: @putvande >> How did you find out you get a blank email? - Well... all the emails go to my email address. And I don't hit F5, I am visiting the page just by clicking on the link in the menu, I don't reload it.

Comment: @Dexa Why? And how can I solve it then?

Comment: Well I wrote how to solve it, check `if(isset($_POST['userName']))` instead of just `if(isset($_POST))` since $_POST is predefined variable which is always set.

Comment: Take a look at csrf, might help you secure your form a little. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_CSRF_Guard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your if statement to

```
if(isset($_POST['userEmail'])
```

As $_POST will be set anytime you visit the site, see [PHP doc for isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Also see [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) as you will also be able to do this:

```
if(!empty($_POST))
```

You can see in the doc:

> [empty()] Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero
>   value. Otherwise returns TRUE.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> - "" (an empty string)
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - 0.0 (0 as a float)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (an empty array)
> - $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

OR in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045279/if-isset-post), [Nemoden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485676/nemoden)'s answer suggests using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` - It's pretty self-explanatory: if the page was requested by the `POST` request method, this statement will be true, however if you have multiple forms on the same page I suggest naming each submit button and checking for that.

Comment: This would still send an email if the username (or email ) is empty

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST)` should be `if(!empty($_POST))`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do not send the form if there was no form data sent.

The condition `if(isset($_POST))` checks whether there is a variable `$_POST` not if there is something in that variable. The `$_POST` array is one of PHP's automatically created superglobals and does always exist.

You need to check if there are some post-variables in that array; e.g.

```
if( !empty( $_POST ) )
```

or better

```
if( !empty( $_POST['userEmail'] ) )
```

…since the post array may have members (i.e. form fields) but those could be empty.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is just an empty predefined array, so when they load the page, `$_POST` is defined. What you need to do is `isset($_POST['name'])`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userName']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userEmail']);
    $phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userPhone']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userMsg'] . $phone);

    $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

    $to = 'myEmail';
    $subject = 'subject';
    $headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fixe it like that :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['userName']) && isset($_POST['userEmail']) && isset($_POST['userPhone']) && isset($_POST['userMsg'])) {
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userName']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userEmail']);
    $phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userPhone']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userMsg'] . $phone);

    $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

    $to = 'myEmail';
    $subject = 'subject';
    $headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

you can however add

```
if(!empty($_POST['userMsg'])
```

to test if the variable is empty or not...

Answer (score 0):

You can give the submit button a name and check if it is clicked or not. This will prevent to send a email whenever the page is loaded.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
   // your code
}
```

Edit the HTML of your submit button like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send!" name="submit">
```

Comment: There is no field `submit`; you should explain where that came from…

Comment: @feeela he is mentioned that `give the submit button a name`

Answer (score 0):

give the name of your submit button like

```
 <span><input type="submit" value="Send!" name="submit"></span>
```

AND check it in php like

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice.
I strongly advice you to start using a PHP framework.

Nevertheless...

The $_POST will always exist, so you can not test it like `if(isset($_POST))`.
To test if your form was submitted you must check if some of the expected POST var do exist.

In your case, something like `if(isset($_POST['userEmail']))` would do the trick or you can add a `name` attribute to your submit button and test it `if(isset($_POST['mySubmitButtonName']))`

Comment: I hate PHP frameworks, I like to do everything myself ;) Thanks though.

Comment: I don't think that mixing HTML and PHP is a good idea mainly because of maintenance and application security

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the *name* of *submit* button

```
<input type="submit" value="Send!" name="send">
```

then u can write the condition when the button is pressed the mail will be send like

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['send'])){

    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userName']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userEmail']);
    $phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userPhone']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userMsg'] . $phone);

    $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

    $to = 'myEmail';
    $subject = 'subject';
    $headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be for the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` acting on the form, try adding the actual page directory or a better solution i would try is to check if is not empty for a specific required field

`if (!empty($_POST['userMsg'])){}`