# using sessions to post data into input using what if

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm trying to create my first if else statement using a 2 page form. At the end of page 1 it uses sessions to save all the post data and automatically insert it into page2 form.

I'm trying to get it were if someone leaves the field blank it will insert Add a Driver into the input.

If the user places info in page 1 however I want it to echo whatever the user typed in page1.

I can successfully get it to echo from page 1 by just using the echo command and I can get it to echo add a driver if the field is left blank. However if a user types into the field its still echoing add a driver and not what he typed via the echo ($_POST['test1']); field. what am i doing wrong?
here is the page the php is in the 2nd input field http://test.solidinsurance.com/page1.php

```
<?php        
if (isset($_POST["test1"])) {
echo "Add a Driver";
} else {
echo ($_POST['test1']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you also checking if the `test1` variable is blank/empty in the code above?

Comment: Please be more clear about which events cause which output.  Show us each example in a separate block of text.

Comment: isset checks to see if its empty and runs the what if statement right? <br>the way i see my code is if test1 is empty echo add a driver otherwise echo test1 from page1

Comment: possible duplicate of [if isset $\_POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045279/if-isset-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed isset to empty
    
    if (empty($_POST["test1"])) {
    echo "Add a Driver";
    } else {
    echo ($_POST['test1']);
    }
    ?>
so if the post is empty it echos add a driver. if the post is not empty it echos whatever the user types in page 1 test1 post.

Comment: And for future reference, you may want to use an `isset()` check along with the `empty()` check... like this: `if (isset($var) && empty($var)) { }`