# Unable to display sum of data in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am using the following environment:

PHP version 5.6
Apache 2.4
O.S Windows 10.

Following is the code for my form and the PHP script that handles the form submission. When I submit the form I get a blank page. It doesn't print "Total:". Also, if I remove the `isset` condition, I get the following error:

> "Notice: Undefined index: value1 in F:\small php projects\addnnum.php
>   on line 5"
>
> "Notice: Undefined index: value2 in F:\small php projects\addnnum.php
>   on line 6"

**addnum.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>PHP - Add two numbers</title>
    <body>
        <form action="addnnum.php" method="post">
            <input type="number" name="value1" value="0" />
            <input type="number" name="value2" value="0" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate values"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**addnnum.php**

```
<?php
echo "Test";

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $value1 = $_POST['value1'];
    $value2 = $_POST['value2'];
    $sum    = $value1 + $value2;

    echo "Total :" . $sum;
}
?>
```

Comment: do you at least have the `echo "Test"` working?

Comment: You could use `echo print_r($_POST);` to debug your request.

Comment: Do you really have `method="post"` on the form in the code you are running? From your problem description, it sounds like you have might be submitting the form with `GET` and then looking for the values in `POST`. If you have added `method="post"` recently, you may be seeing a cached version that still uses `GET`, depending on your PHP config.

Comment: @radoh you don't need `echo` in front of `print_r`

Comment: your code is working fine on my end.. perhaps try this approach from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045279/if-isset-post)

Comment: @CodeGodie- yes echo test is working.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - if i use get its working, not working for post though.

Comment: is this a config issue ? $_POST seems to be not working.

Comment: Hi I am using PHP storm . 10 . if i try this using the interpreter configured in PHP storm its not working. if i access using localhost its working, seems like a config issue in PH storm. I had  recently integrated Xdebug into php storm. it may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the issue. It seems to be issue in PHP storm version 10.

I have uninstalled ver 10 and installed ver 9. It works perfectly ok. Here's the link

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206999125-PhPStorm-10-does-not-allow-POST-method

Hope this helps..