# Adding else to rename() function

Tags: php

I'm writing a simple `rename` form that renames the folder name. It works fine, but if the file doesn't exist PHP gives me an error.

```
<form> 
    <input type="text"  value="folder name you want to rename">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];

rename("../folders/".$_POST['name']."","../renamed/new-name");
?>
```

The code works perfectly, but I want to add an if/else statement because when I run the script for a folder that does not exist, I get this error.

> Does not exist

I want to remove the error, and simply output "doesn't exist".

Comment: Try to adjust according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13045314/7735285), `if (isset($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["name"])) {...`

Comment: @wpcoder didn't work with me check the answers and u will know what i mean .. thanks for try btw <3

Comment: My comment didn't meant to be a solution, its only a hint to modify your code accordingly. @Rajdeeb did answer the same just in different algorithm. its all about `if else` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just use a simple if statement to check that `rename()` worked, since it returns a boolean (`true`, or `false`) value. Read more on [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php).

So you could write something along these lines:

```
if(rename("../folders/".$_POST['name']."","../renamed/new-name"))
{
    echo "Folder renamed";
    // more code...
}
else
{
    echo "Folder does not exist.";
    // more code...
}
```

Comment: No problem... Let me know if you need any help!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you're able to send the form data without any `name` attribute or how you're able to get the data using `$_POST` when there's no `method` attribute included in your form. By default, it would have been sending form data using `GET` method. I believe you're taking care of all these things.

Now having said that, first check whether *that* particular directory exists or not, and then rename it accordingly or just prints a message *directory doesn't exist* if the directory user is trying to rename doesn't exist.

```
if(file_exists("../folders/".$_POST['name'])){
    rename("../folders/".$_POST['name'],"../renamed/new-name");
}else{
    echo "directory doesn't exist";
}
```

Here's the reference: **http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php**

> *file_exists — Checks whether a file or directory exists*

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["name"]) && file_exists("../folders/".$_POST['name'])) {
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
rename("../folders/".$_POST['name']."","../renamed/new-name")
}
else
{
echo "Folder does not exist.";
//ToDo
}
```

Just another different simple algorithm.

I rather prefer this algorithm if you need to make `rename()` more functional and complicated. And it validate the form text box at same time.

For example, if you wish to generate the new name at server's side I would go for this solution.