# Variables are not recognized when select a value with combobox

Tags: php, if-statement, select

I have the following code and I want to show some divs (to input IMEI or Serial Number) but just if the selected value is Phone or tablet (for imei) and if the elected value is Computer, Portable Drive, router etc etc how the Serial Number Div, i've tried this way but it keep saying this:

> **Notice: Undefined index: value in C:...\create.php on line 139
>
>   Notice: Undefined index: value in C:...\create.php on line
>   141**
>  **Line 139:** `$_POST['value'];` 
> **Line 141:**
>   `switch($_POST['value']){`

The **main code**: (I have more inputs, I'm just giving an exemple of what my comboBox looks like)

```
<select name="value">
   <option value="Phone" <?php echo !empty($ativo) && $ativo == 'Phone' ? 
   'selected' : ''; ?>>Phone</option>
   <option value="IPAD" <?php echo !empty($ativo) && $ativo == 'IPAD' ? 
   'selected' : ''; ?>>IPAD</option>
</select>
```

And the **PHP** code:

```
$_POST['value'];
switch($_POST['value'])
{
    case 'Phone':
        echo 'I have an IMEI';
    break;
    case 'Computer':
        echo 'I have a Serial Number';
    break;
    case 'Bag':
        echo 'Im just a bag';
    break;
    default:
            // Something went wrong or form has been tampered.
}
```

**Node:** I just put "echo" to do an experiment just to see if it works but it keep saying the same!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: nop, it didn't helped me solving my problem.

Comment: You are not checking whether `$_POST['value'];` is assigned. You are getting these notices when you haven't yet posted your form. See also [if-isset-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045279/if-isset-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try with changing the !empty($ativo) to if(isset($ativo)) and $_POST['value'] with if(isset($_POST['value'])), it might solve your problem.

Made changes in your code with below ...

In main.php

```
<select name="value">
   <option value="Phone" <?php if((isset($ativo) and !empty($ativo)) && $ativo == 'Phone'){ echo  'selected';} else{ echo '';} ?>>Phone</option>
   <option value="IPAD" <?php if((isset($ativo) and !empty($ativo)) && $ativo == 'IPAD'){ echo  'selected';} else{ echo '';} ?>>IPAD</option>
</select>
```

PHP code like below

```
 if(isset($_POST['value']) and !empty($_POST['value'])){

    switch($_POST['value'])
    {
        case 'Phone':
            echo 'I have an IMEI';
        break;
        case 'Computer':
            echo 'I have a Serial Number';
        break;
        case 'Bag':
            echo 'Im just a bag';
        break;
        default:
                // Something went wrong or form has been tampered.
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Unfortunally it keeps showing me the same error.. "Undefined index: value in C\... line 141"
I really didn't get the point of it because on the select the variables work but it i try to use "$ativo" out of the select it shows me the same mistake.. :/

Comment: Try with isset along with not empty, find updated code in main answer

Comment: well, the error disapear, that's good, but it doesn't output the echos :/

Comment: then it might be $_POST['value'] is empty

Comment: It's kinda impossible.. because the value is what is typed on the combobox so it shouldn't be empty :/

Comment: Okay, it kinda works so far thank you! 
But.. it just do the `if condition` when i click on "submit" button, and i wanted it to do the `if condition` when i choose the input even without submit it, is it possible?

Comment: yes, you can do, for that you need to call the onclick/onselect function on that input field and call the ajax function to get the the response