# Using if(isset($_POST[''])) method to see if the user enter the data so in will store them , and if not so will not save when i refresh the page

Tags: function, php-7.3

i want to use if(isset($_POST['name'])) loop to test if user enter data so it will store it in database and if not so dont store it even when i refresh the page!!

i've tried to use if(isset($_POST['name'])) loop to test if user enter data so it will store it in database and if not so dont store it even when i refresh the page but doesnt work ! and when i refresh the page it store the last data that i've tried before!!

this is index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul><?php
  require "controller/database.php";
  require "controller/users.php";


  $user=new Users();
  $user->insertUser($_POST['name'],$_POST['age'],$_POST['email']);


?></ul>

<form action="" method="POST">


<input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Name"><br><br>

<input type="number" name="age" required placeholder="Age" ><br><br>
<input type="text" name="email" required placeholder="Email" ><br><br>

<button type="submit" name="insert" value="Add Data To Database"></button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the users.php file :

```
 <?php
 class Users extends DB {
    function insertUser($name,$age,$email){

     $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, age, email )
    VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$email')";

            $res=$this->insert($query);

    //return $this->select("SELECT * FROM `users`");
```

}
}

i've tried to use if(isset($_POST['name'])) loop to test if user enter data so it will store it in database and if not so dont store it even when i refresh the page but doesnt work ! and when i refresh the page it store the last data that i've tried before!!

Please help!!

it show this error and store the data at the same time !

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion de paie\index.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion de paie\index.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion de paie\index.php on line 10

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition before you create user,  in index file

index.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul><?php
  require "controller/database.php";
  require "controller/users.php";

  if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['age']) && isset($_POST['email']){
    $user=new Users();
    $user->insertUser($_POST['name'],$_POST['age'],$_POST['email']);
  }

?></ul>

<form action="" method="POST">


<input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Name"><br><br>

<input type="number" name="age" required placeholder="Age" ><br><br>
<input type="text" name="email" required placeholder="Email" ><br><br>

<button type="submit" name="insert" value="Add Data To Database"></button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also don't put user inputs inside a query without sanitize, i suggest always to controll user inputs before you enter in you sql query:

users.php :

```
 <?php
 class Users extends DB {
    function insertUser($name,$age,$email){

    // Sanitize your data always don't trust user
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
    $age = mysql_real_escape_string($age);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, age, email )
    VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$email')";

    $res=$this->insert($query); //return $this->select("SELECT * FROM `users`");
```

Hope to be the needed question :)

Comment: Unexpected '{'      :     if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['age']) && isset($_POST['email']){
    $user=new Users();
    $user->insertUser($_POST['name'],$_POST['age'],$_POST['email']);
  
    
  }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `isset`, you should use `!empty` ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045279/if-isset-post)), as `isset` doesn't work for arrays. `isset($_POST["anything"])` always returns true, while `!empty($_POST["anything"])` only returns true if `$_POST["anything"]` exists.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul><?php
    require "controller/database.php";
    require "controller/users.php";

    if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['age']) && !empty($_POST['email']) {
        $user=new Users();
        $user->insertUser($_POST['name'],$_POST['age'],$_POST['email']);
    }

?></ul>

<form action="" method="POST">


<input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Name"><br><br>

<input type="number" name="age" required placeholder="Age" ><br><br>
<input type="text" name="email" required placeholder="Email" ><br><br>

<button type="submit" name="insert" value="Add Data To Database"></button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, you should use Prepared statements.

Comment: Unexpected '{' : if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['age']) && isset($_POST['email']){ $user=new Users(); $user->insertUser($_POST['name'],$_POST['age'],$_POST['email']); }

Comment: @NaimBouallagui Ok, maybe it's because of the `<ul>`s…
I don't see a reason why you need them.
Does it change something if you delete `<ul>` and `</ul>` and make an empty line between `<body>`and `<?php`?

Also, this error often is caused if you make `<?` instead of `<?php`.
Did you check that this occurs nowhere in the document?